# How to make this simple method even shorter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have very simple method in my application. I wonder if there is way to make it even shorter.

```
def is_enough_words_to_play_game?
    if Word.verified.size > 5
        true
    else
        false
    end
end
```

Comment: `def is_enough_words_to_play_game?; Word.verified.size > 5; end`

Comment: `def i;Word.verified.size>5;end`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just write:

```
def is_enough_words_to_play_game?
  Word.verified.size > 5
end
```

Because `Word.verified.size > 5` returns already a boolean.

Or IMHO more readable:

```
MIN_WORDS_FOR_GAME = 6

def enough_words?
  Word.verified.size >= MIN_WORDS_FOR_GAME
end
```

Comment: Does it make sense to define such simple method?

Comment: @HubertJakubiak This is *exactly* how you define methods in Ruby that are clean, simple, and easy to understand. The only thing I'm concerned about here is the magical number `5` which should be some kind of constant somewhere so its meaning is made clear.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak Yes becasue `is_enough_words_to_play_game?` gives the reader some context to work with, although your choice of method name could possibly be shortened.

Comment: @HubertJakubiak And the logic of the method may change over time, while the semantics remain the same.

Comment: Last snippet is more maintainable too :)

Comment: @spickermann Where I should keep constant `MIN_WORDS_FOR_GAME` in my application? Just before defining method?

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as

```
def is_enough_words_to_play_game?
  Word.verified.size > 5 ? true:false
end
```

Comment: The ternary is pointless in this context, because the condition already returns a boolean.